# How do I find which program is using port 80 in Windows?

Tags: windows, port

How do I find which program is using port 80 in Windows?

I can't find it.

Comment: This question would be better suited for http://superuser.com/

Comment: see [How can you find out which process is listening on a port on Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23718720/1290264)

Comment: so many people are viewing this question and upvoting my answer that I think we should re-consider opening it

Comment: netstat -aof | findstr :80

Comment: @Technotronic: Your answer doesn't say anything not well covered on the question this is a duplicate of, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/19255965/103167

Comment: @BenVoigt and still gets upvotes weekly by people who search for a specific answer and not a generic one.

Comment: @Technotronic: That's not a positive thing.  It means twice as much content to maintain.

Comment: @BenVoigt I think this should be reopened because it's not a duplicate. Port 80 is a special case and the question has not been properly answered. Port 80 will always show PID 4 (System) when ever a process has bound to the HTTP.SYS kernel-mode driver, which is used by many different services like WSMAN or WCF. One would need to use netsh to find the process, and none of the answers here cover that rather common scenario.

Comment: @JonC: That sounds like a "Why does HTTP.SYS have port 80 open?" question, since the answer to the question raised here would be HTTP.SYS

Answer (score 212, accepted):

Start menu → *Accessories* → right click on "Command prompt". In the menu, click *"Run as Administrator"* (on Windows XP you can just run it as usual), run `netstat -anb`, and then look through output for your program.

BTW, Skype by default tries to use ports 80 and 443 for incoming connections.

You can also run `netstat -anb >%USERPROFILE%\ports.txt` followed by `start %USERPROFILE%\ports.txt` to open the port and process list in a text editor, where you can search for the information you want.

You can also use PowerShell to parse `netstat` output and present it in a better way (or process it any way you want):

```
$proc = @{};
Get-Process | ForEach-Object { $proc.Add($_.Id, $_) };
netstat -aon | Select-String "\s*([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+):([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+):([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)?\s+([^\s]+)" | ForEach-Object {
    $g = $_.Matches[0].Groups;
    New-Object PSObject |
        Add-Member @{ Protocol =           $g[1].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ LocalAddress =       $g[2].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ LocalPort =     [int]$g[3].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ RemoteAddress =      $g[4].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ RemotePort =         $g[5].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ State =              $g[6].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ PID =           [int]$g[7].Value  } -PassThru |
        Add-Member @{ Process = $proc[[int]$g[7].Value] } -PassThru;
#} | Format-Table Protocol,LocalAddress,LocalPort,RemoteAddress,RemotePort,State -GroupBy @{Name='Process';Expression={$p=$_.Process;@{$True=$p.ProcessName; $False=$p.MainModule.FileName}[$p.MainModule -eq $Null] + ' PID: ' + $p.Id}} -AutoSize
} | Sort-Object PID | Out-GridView
```

Also it does not require elevation to run.

Comment: It'll output too much,but I only want information about port 80

Comment: netstat -anb | findstr :80

Comment: Then you either need to watch through list carefully or install some additional software. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx for example.

Comment: Anton, it will chop process names.

Comment: @Anton Tykhyy，this way I can't see the programme name,just numbers.

Comment: Initially (not sure about current situation) Skype was using peer-to-peer connections for calls and chats: this way they don't need huge infrastructure to support millions of clients, so clients attempt to connect directly to each other. Ports 80 and 443 are less likely to be blocked for incoming connections, so they attempt to use it where possible.

Answer (score 228):

Type in the command:

```
netstat -aon | findstr :80
```

It will show you all processes that use port 80. Notice the *pid* (process id) in the right column.

If you would like to free the port, go to [Task Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager), sort by *pid* and close those processes.

-**a** displays all connections and listening ports.

-**o** displays the owning process ID associated with each connection.

-**n** displays addresses and port numbers in numerical form.

Comment: And to find what is the process running it: tasklist /svc /FI "PID eq 1348" (thanks to @Quang-Trinh)

Comment: netstat -ano ^| findstr "0.0.0.0:80 check Web_Ports_Inspector.bat http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2015/05/how-to-check-whats-using-port-80-or-443-in-a-single-step-web-port-inspector.html

Comment: Is it possible to close the connection?

Comment: free the port without killing the process?

Comment: Please note that `findstr :80` will match every port INCLUDING "80", so besides port 80, it will also matches programs on port 8009, 8080, etc.

Comment: What to do if PID 4 is listening on :80? "4" is the system, on Windows.

Answer (score 17):

If you want to be really fancy, download [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) from [Sysinternals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysinternals):

> TCPView is a Windows program that will
>   show you detailed listings of all TCP
>   and UDP endpoints on your system,
>   including the local and remote
>   addresses and state of TCP
>   connections. On Windows Server 2008,
>   Vista, and XP, TCPView also reports
>   the name of the process that owns the
>   endpoint. TCPView provides a more
>   informative and conveniently presented
>   subset of the Netstat program that
>   ships with Windows.

Answer (score 14):

Right click on "Command prompt" or "PowerShell", in menu click "Run as Administrator" (on Windows XP you can just run it as usual).

As Rick Vanover mentions in *[See what process is using a TCP port in Windows Server 2008](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/see-what-process-is-using-a-tcp-port-in-windows-server-2008/)*

> The following command will show what network traffic is in use at the
>   port level:
>
> ```
> Netstat -a -n -o
> ```

or

```
Netstat -a -n -o >%USERPROFILE%\ports.txt
```

(to open the port and process list in a text editor, where you can search for information you want)

Then,

> with the PIDs listed in the netstat output, you can follow up with the
>   Windows Task Manager (taskmgr.exe) or run a script with a specific PID
>   that is using a port from the previous step. You can then use the
>   "tasklist" command with the specific PID that corresponds to a port in
>   question.

Example:

```
tasklist /svc /FI "PID eq 1348"
```

Answer (score 12):

Use this nifty freeware utility:

[CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) is network monitoring software that displays the list of all currently opened TCP/IP and UDP ports on your local computer.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use [NETSTAT](https://ss64.com/nt/netstat.html) on the command-line:

```
netstat util
```

Comment: This will only display the help text (with all the different options/switches). Which option should be used? Should it be `-a` - *"-a   Display All connections and listening ports."*?

Comment: Or [`-a -n -o`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960750/how-do-i-find-which-program-is-using-port-80-in-windows/20509221#20509221)?