# XAMPP PORT 80 is Busy / EasyPHP error in Apache configuration file:

Tags: apache, xampp, easyphp, port80

This problem has completely shot my entire day. I reformatted my old windows XP comp and tried installing XAMPP only to find that when i try to start Apache xampp claims port 80 is busy....WHAT DOES THAT EVEN MEAN?

So I tried just uninstalling and moving to EasyPHP instead and when I installed that I get the error "error in Apache configuration file: the system cannot execute the specified program"

No, I do not have Skype or any other programs really for that matter at this point, like I said I JUST REFORMATTED so idk whats going on.

I would love to get this fixed, but if you leave me a answer please be specific on directions bc I'm only programming, never been to big on IT and playing with command lines and what not for me isn't to much fun.

Answer (score 26):

Things to be done to free port 80:

1. check if skype is running, exit from skype
2. check services.msc if web deployment agent service is running
3. check if IIS is running, stop it.

Once you start apache, you can sign into skype.

Comment: Great catch on Web Deployment Agent Service!

Comment: I use Netstat of XAMPP and see Skype used port 80. Exit Skype then Apache can start, but how can I use both? Can change config port for Skype or other way?

Comment: In skype go to Tools->Options->Advanced->Connection and uncheck "Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections.". Now both Xampp and skype will run simultaneously :)

Answer (score 17):

Only one process can use port 80 at a time. Port 80 is the default port for web servers, so when you navigate to websites over HTTP, you are actually navigating to that server's port 80 by default (when you use HTTPS, the port is 443).

You can try to hunt down all the programs that are running on port 80, but there's an easier way that will work for development. When running XAMPP, click "Config" under "Apache". Replace `Listen 80` with `Listen 8080` and `ServerName localhost:80` to `ServerName localhost:8080`.

Then, when you want to look at your masterpiece, navigate to `http://localhost:8080` in your browser.

Answer (score 8):

**SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS)**
 SSRS can remain active even if you uninstall SQL Server. 
To stop the service:

Open SQL Server Configuration Manager.
Select “SQL Server Services” in the left-hand pane.
Double-click “SQL Server Reporting Services”.
Hit Stop.
Switch to the Service tab and set the Start Mode to “Manual”.

---

**Skype**
Irritatingly, Skype can switch to port 80. To disable it, select 
`Tools > Options > Advanced > Connection` then uncheck 
`“Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections”`.

---

**IIS (Microsoft Internet Information Server)**

For Windows 7 (or vista) its **the most likely culprit**. You can stop the service from the command line.

Open command line `cmd.exe` and type:

```
net stop was /y
```

For older versions of Windows type:

```
net stop iisadmin /y
```

---

**Other**

If this does not solve the problem further detective work is necessary if IIS, SSRS and Skype are not to blame. Enter the following on the command line:

```
netstat -ao
```

The active TCP addresses and ports will be listed. Locate the line with local address “0.0.0.0:80″ and note the PID value. Start Task Manager. Navigate to the Processes tab and, if necessary, click View > Select Columns to ensure “PID (Process Identifier)” is checked. You can now locate the PID you noted above. The description and properties should help you determine which application is using the port.

Comment: This is really awesome xampp can be funny some time

Answer (score 7):

Run this in command prompt:

`netstat -ano | find ":80"`

It will show you what process (PID) is listening on port 80.

From there you can open task manager, make sure you have PID selected in columns view option, and find the matching PID to find what process it is.

If its svchost.exe you'll have to dig more (see `tasklist /svc`).

I had this happen to me recently and it wasn't any of the popular answers like Skype either, could be Adobe, Java, anything really.

Answer (score 4):

Port 80 might be busy with other application like IIS. If you don't want to stop it, you can change the apache port. Here is the way..

1. go to the C:\xampp\apache\conf (directory where you installed xampp). Now, locate the `httpd.conf`.
2. Open it with any text editor (like notepad) and go the line that says `Listen 80`
3. Change this with any other port (like `Listen 1234`)
4. Save the file. Restart the server and go ahead.

Comment: I had to also make change in `C:\xampp\xampp-control.ini` file and change the port from 80 to 1234

Answer (score 2):

xampp port 80 is busy when some other application is using the same port at that time. This can be solved by using one of the following methods:

1. Detect the application which is using the port 80 and close it.
2. This one is more efficient. xampp installs apache server with default port 80. So, you can change this port manually to any number.

Just find the httpd.conf file in xampp installation and replace the following line of code.

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:1234
Listen 80
```

to any port number of your choice. Here, i have taken 8000.

```
#Listen 12.34.56.78:1234
Listen 8000
```

Find the following code in the same file httpd.conf

```
ServerName localhost
```

Replace with the following, take the same number you have used in upper code.

```
ServerName localhost:8000
```

For detailed answer, check http://webolute.com/blog/programming/this-may-be-due-to-a-blocked-port-missing-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Just do one thing

open **skype > tools > advance or advance settings** Change port 80 to something else 7395

Restart your system then start Apache

Answer (score 1):

I've found that the biggest culprit for taking up port 80 on newer Windows installs is the BranchCache Service (#3) in this list...

1. SQL Server Reporting Services
2. Web Deployment Agent Service
3. BranchCache
4. World Wide Web Publishing Service

These 4 service probably cover 90% of the *native* Windows Services that take up port 80.

The other 10% is the hidden HTTP.sys service/driver which takes port 80 when another service requests it. Run this to disable it, and reboot.

```
sc config http start= disabled
```

Aside from Skype, TeamViewer is also very commonly installed software, and will take port 80 if not configured otherwise.

List taken from: [Opening Up Port 80 For Apache to Use On Windows](http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/opening-up-port-80-for-apache-to-use-on-windows)

Comment: I had the same problem and I found out that : **BranchCache** and **PrintSpooler** used port 80/443

Answer (score 1):

If you are running VMWare Workstation , you need to stop the VmWare Workstation server - port 443 as well

Answer (score 1):

So I have faced the same problem when trying to start apache service and I would like to share my solutions with you.
Here is some notes about services or programs that may use port 80:

1. **Skype**: skype uses port 80/443 by default. You can change this from tools->options->
   advanced->connections and uncheck the checkbox **"use port 80 and 443 for addtional incoming      connections".**
2. **IIS**: IIS uses port 80 be default so you need to shut down it. You can use the following two commands
     net stop w3svc
     net stop iisadmin
3. **SQL Server Reporting Service**: You need to stop this service because it may take port 80 if IIS is not running. Go to local services and stop it.

These options work great with me and I can start apache service without errors.

The other option is to change apache listen port from **httpd.conf** and set another port number.

Hope this solution helps anyone who face the same problem again.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because some other programs running in your system is using the default port 80 used for http service by apache server in xampp/easy php.

Some programs like skype usually use port 80.
so find such program and remove it ...

For finding programs listening port 80 refer [Port 80 listening programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960750/how-to-find-which-programme-is-using-port-80-in-windows)

Comment: I've also turned off the firewall , uninstallled and re installed xampp and reformatted x2 more today and still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the Service running on the PID that is blocking the service from Task manager->Services

In case this isn't of help go to `Task Manager->Services` 
Go to the Services button on bottom right of window and stop the Web Deployment Agent Service. Retry starting Apache . That might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is because port 80 is used by some other application. Try to reconfigure port.