# Apache server is not workoing

Tags: xampp, wamp

Please tell me what it has problem when i click on Apache start button it does not start please tell me what mistake i did

[image]

Comment: This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window here on SO

Comment: i am get my point. it just a skpe port problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XAMPP PORT 80 is Busy / EasyPHP error in Apache configuration file:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103924/xampp-port-80-is-busy-easyphp-error-in-apache-configuration-file)

Comment: if you have skype installed uncheck port no 80 -->disable Skype usage of and listening on port 80 and port 443, open the Skype window, then click on Tools menu and select Options. Click on Advanced tab, and go to Connection sub-tab. Untick or uncheck the check box for Use port 80 and 443 as an alternatives for incoming connections option.