# Cannot connect to Apache Server using XAMPP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Recently, I installed XAMPP Control Panel to do PHP project. But it does not allow to connect to Apache server. It gives following error message in XAMPP Control Panel.

My laptop has Window 10 and have Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2015 and Skype installed.

[Screenshot of XAMPP Control Panel which gives error when try to connect to Apache Server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ta7v.jpg)

Comment: Second thought its skype, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22994888/why-skype-using-http-or-https-ports-80-and-443

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the port of either of the one (skype or apache).
Follow these links to do so:

- **Change Skype's port:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/23928017/8840862
- **Change Apache's Port:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/17127428/8840862

*If still you find any issue, feel free to comment.*

Comment: Great answer. Changing Skype port didn't work. But I changed Apache port into 1234 as it is mentioned in the link you posted. Now Apache server is connecting. But project is not working with XAMPP. When I run it with Chrome, it gives following error.This localhost page can’t be found

No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost/Car%20Exporter/index.html
Search Google for localhost Car Exporter index
HTTP ERROR 404

Comment: This is so because now your apache is listening at port 1234. Therefore http://localhost will not work directly as it means http://localhost:80. To make it work if you write http://localhost:1234 it should work.
Try this suggestion, if still, you feel any issue let me know.

Comment: Superb **Ronit**. Your suggestion works very well. Thank You very much for your help.

Comment: I changed the port number of Apache Server to 1234 as you said. Will it create issues in the future for other programs in the laptop ? I mean, will it be a problem for my Visual Studio local server ? Can you explain any other side effects ?