# installed xampp in windows 8 64bit.?

Tags: xampp

i installed xampp but got apache error after the installation...im new to this server concept....and when i placed my files in xampp folder in c drive which is the root ...and when i use localhost/xampp/file.html it doesnt show up...whats the problem behind it...

ERROR: Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
8:21:50 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
8:21:50 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
8:21:50 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! I guess you could format your question a bit better (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and in your specific case I guess you have another process listening on port 80 (maybe Skype?).

Comment: i dont have skype installed right now...is there any app that accessing it???

Comment: maybe utorrent or idm????

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960750/how-to-find-which-program-is-using-port-80-in-windows (I found it googling "windows applications listening to port 80")

Answer (score 0):

Try using port 8080 rather than 80 if Windows 8 is involved. You will have to find the config file in Xampp

Answer (score 0):

Most likely Skype on windows 8.1 (comes installed), however I read somewhere that other (earlier) installed MS SQL programs prevents Apache from running because of conflicting port numbers. MS Visual Studio (supports pre-installed MS Office?!?) is also using this. This user simply uninstalled the older MS SQL file(s).

Skype is -just like Xampp- using ports 80 and 443 and **those port numbers cannot be changed anymore in the newer versions**. I opened Skype and re-opend my Xampp control-panel and started both Apache and Msql; both started running and you can see Apache is running with ports 80 and 443. Without closing I opened Skype again and was able to make a connection. With re-opening the Xampp control panel, I could see that Apache was still in the running-mode. I opened my web browser and typed "localhost" and the Xampp screen appeared; php-administration and the phonebook both worked. So I think Skype is automaticly changing its default port numbers.
Works for me, hope the same for other users.