# WAMP - Your port 80 is actually used - Error

Tags: apache, wamp, skype, port80

I installed Wamp server and when I open it, it never gets online. It always stays orange (offline). I read something about Skype, but I don't even have Skype installed and when I go to Apache > Service > Test port 80 it says: Your port 80 is actually used

Any ideas how to make this work?

Comment: Your port 80 may be used by IIS, or you can find out what is using it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960750/how-to-find-which-program-is-using-port-80-in-windows

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I've solved this today!! If you are on Windows, You go to

```
"Control Panel" >> "System And Security" >>  "Administrative Tools" >> "Component Services" >> "Services (LOCAL)"
```

Now, since you are using WAMP and not IIS you should disable the "World Wide Web Publishing Service" and the "Web Deployment Agent Service". You are good to go.

If this doesn't work you probably have Skype using Port 80 (if you actually have Skype). (If you have IIS installed you should also disable it. But if you don't have it installed you shouldn't worry!)

Answer (score 9):

If you are using windows machine the port 80 is used by the IIS Server and Skype also used the port 80. that why it says that port 80 is already used. 
To avoid the conflict,change  the port number of the **wamp server to some other number,for example 5050.**

for changing the port number of the wamp server go to:
**C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf**

In that file change the listen port to 5050.

**#Listen 12.34.56.78:5050**

**Listen 0.0.0.0:5050**

**Listen [::0]:5050**

**and you access the wamp server at localhost:5050**

It works for me and I hope it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in windows, try:

> netstat -b

on Commandline, this will give you an information what file is using port 80, it should look like this:

```
[httpd.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             YOUR_PC:0                   ABHÖREN
[httpd.exe]
  TCP    [::1]:80               YOUR_PC:53342               HERGESTELLT
[httpd.exe]
  TCP    [::1]:80               YOUR_PC:53343               HERGESTELLT
[httpd.exe]
  TCP    [::1]:80               YOUR_PC:53344               HERGESTELLT
```