# Wamp server icon indicates in orange color

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

Wamp server icon in system tray indicates in orange color and i could not be able to connect.

When checking the apache services it displays the error as follows:
your port 80 is actually used by information not available (might be skype)

I even checked with the other programs that whether they are using the port 80. the answer is no and I have not installed skype/IIS on my machine.

I have followed what is mentioned in the following link also which is failure again. [WAMP - Your port 80 is actually used - Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016388/wamp-your-port-80-is-actually-used-error)

i copied httpd.conf from another machine's wamp folder. stopped all services and restarted It was not working again.

Please any one help me on this to solve this.

Comment: what is the output of `netstat -anb`

Comment: It displays many number of IP address with port numbers. I even checked whether the 127.0.0.1:80 is being used. but the answer is no still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out if something is using port 80 and what that thing is launch a command windows using 'Run as Administrator' and do :

```
netstat -aon | find ":80"
```

The result might look something like this

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       6948
TCP    192.168.2.11:52629     190.93.245.58:80       ESTABLISHED     6420
TCP    192.168.2.11:52630     198.252.206.16:80      ESTABLISHED     6420
TCP    [::]:80                [::]:0                 LISTENING       6948
```

The numbers at the end of each line are PID's so take the PID number from above and do

```
tasklist /fi "PID eq 6948"
```

You should see something like

```
Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage
========================= ======== ================ =========== ============
httpd.exe                     6948 Services                   0     24,688 K
```

Although the program using port 80 may be different.

And thats the program that is using port 80, its Apache in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I once have this problem, and found the problem that apache server is ***NOT*** actually installed.
Try click on Apache->service in wamp's trasy icon. Click on "Install service". Cmd will be opened, press enter. Restart all service, and put it online.
Hope this helps.