# Your port 80 is not actually used

Tags: php, mysql, apache, wamp

I have been using wamp 2.0 version for about a year. After which I decided to upgrade to a newer version of 2.2 or 2.5. I uninstalled the 2.0 version and copied all my files to another location. After the new version installation apache did not startup. I test the port 80 and it displays **"Your port 80 is not actually used"**. I have tried as many as possible installation and deletion of the wamp folder before installing another version. But after series of test the 2.0 version is still working perfectly when installed again, but I insists on using the newer version, just to get the new features to be used. Any help will be appreciated. I have google searched for over 24 hours now. Fellow programmer please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using Skype? It can occupy port 80 which will prevent apache from using it.

Comment: You can find out ports are open by opening a cmd session.
Then type 'netstat –a' and press enter. Look for port 80 to see if it is use.

Comment: I don't have Skype or teamweaver installed and I tested the port using wamp >> apache >> services >> test port 80 and this displayed "your port 80 is not actually used".

Comment: Have you looked in the `Apache error log` and/or the `MySQL error log` and/or the `Windows Event Log` for messages from Apache or MySQL.[Start here and first identify if it is Apache or MySQL that is not starting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671456/wampserver-orange-icon/21678795#21678795)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016388/wamp-your-port-80-is-actually-used-error?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

You might not be started the MySql Service.
So Answer in steps:

**START APACHE**

1. Left click on icon -> Apache- > Services -> Install Service
2. Leftclick on icon -> Apache- > Services -> Start/Resume Service Left
3. click on icon -> Apache- > Services -> Test Port 80

(Step 3 will open command prompt "Your port 80 is not actually used" showing in your case. So u have started apache already. If port 80 is used by another program like skype it will appear there too.It will be another [TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671456/wampserver-orange-icon))

NOW **START MYSQL**

1. Left click on icon -> MySql- > Services -> Install Service
2. Leftclick on icon -> MySq- > Services -> Start/Resume Service Left,

LEFT CLICK ON ICON AND RESTART ALL SERVICE

Answer (score 2):

well, this happened to me as well, so, I searched a bit and found very very nice solution. Now a days I'm using **[Ampps](http://www.ampps.com/)**, give it a try, you'll love it.

PS. I used wamp for 4 years, I was a big fan of wamp, but now I'm in love with Ampps :)

As per **Shomz** comment

to prevent Skype from using `port 80`, Login to Skype, then Click `Tools->Options`(or just press `ctrl+,`) Then on the left side, click on `Advanced` and Choose `Connection`, then on right side remove check of check box saying

> Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections.

[image]

and restart Skype.

have a good day.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question but I had the same problem and the solution was easy at my side.

My server was listening to port 8080. So when I tested port 80 I showed the error the questioner is having. I opened httpd.conf in a text editor. httpd.conf is located at.

```
wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf
```

On line 62 or so you need to make sure Apache is listening to port 80. Set the value of that line to:

`Listen 80`

Save the file, and restart All Services on WAMP.

Now, its time for a test.

- Start task manager
- Go to Services tab and find wampapache64
- Remember that PID.
- Then, go to the commander
- run the `netstat -ao` command (more info https://technet.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/bb490947.aspx)
- You should see all Active Connections
- One of these connections is `0.0.0.0:80` and it has a specific PID.
- Check if that PID matches with the PID wampapache64 is using.
- Celebrate your victory if they match.

Comment: Great! I did not remember `netstat -ao`. Another way to check the ports is with `Win`+`R`+`resmon` on **Network** tab and then on **Listening Ports** subtab. The advantage is that here you can see not only the PID, but the name of the process and kill it, just in case you are planning to [change ports](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35208958/1326147) due to, for example, Skype incompatibilities.

Answer (score 0):

it is too late for answering this question....
i also faced this problem. When my port 80 is never being used, i reinstalled wamp server again. Now it runs fluently

Comment: this should be a comment