# Installation of WAMP SERVER

Tags: wampserver

I am trying to install WAMP SERVER on Windows 7 PC. After completing installation I typed localhost/phpmyadmin/ as suggested. But the error is "Site can't be reached". Also when I searched on it google says that green icon should appear on icon, but it is not so... What do I do? Should I try 2.5 version instead of latest 3.0.4 or any other suggestions?

Comment: This is not good website for your problem, look for a wamp forum and try to be more specific in your question. enable logs and view them, seek for errors, try another installation instruction guide to follow

Comment: What colour is the wampmanager icon in the system tray?

Comment: @ilansch If OP goes to the WAMPServer forum he will probably get me, so here is just fine

Comment: Have you created a hosts file Windows 7 comes with it all commented out. `windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` and it should contain 2 lines `127.0.0.1 localhost` and `::1 localhost`

Comment: Did you look in the expansion area of the system tray. Click the little shevron and other apps icons will appear

Answer (score 0):

check what port number you apache http.conf is trying to acquire.
Also do check if any other application is using that port.

Skype (usually does).

Also try Changing the listen port number to 8080
in httpd.conf
Listen 0.0.0.0:8080

and try 
http://localhost:8080

similar link:
[WAMP - Your port 80 is actually used - Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016388/wamp-your-port-80-is-actually-used-error)

Comment: @ilansch,@RiggsFolly thank you so much for help!! Regards.