# Wamp error in opening .error showing again

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I have installed Wamp server but not able to use PHP admin my button shows green but not able to login to PHP admin the port which I am using is it whenever I open the localhost it goes to 8080 so once i in the address bar change it to a t from 8080 to 80 in(already in  httpd.conf changes to 80 still 8080 opens up) it opens up  and connects  to the database.but when I try to open a PHP admin want to see my files in database can't login
Where m i going wrong

Comment: are you sure Wamp Database was connected? which kind off error was return ?

Comment: It's is connected as my pages are showing up

Comment: then you must share your code here so we can check where is wrong

Comment: Code .....? I think something wrong with port.

Comment: Port used by apache 8080.I changed to 80 in https.conf still it is taking 8080.80 is not used.

Comment: Okay, same issue i faced. having Skype in your system? then please change that port. and then start wamp

Comment: No Skype. ...and port 80 is unused free

Comment: Okay check here  i found same question that you have [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016388/wamp-your-port-80-is-actually-used-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016388/wamp-your-port-80-is-actually-used-error)

Comment: Mine is showing green.pages are opening means able to connect to database but can't open phpmyadmin

Comment: Okay create one php file and put this code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check it about your DB

Comment: code `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and check it about your DB.what I need to look

Comment: Ok it's is showing up default port 3306 which is correct

Comment: Did you use the wampmanager menu to change the port that APache use, or did you do it maually?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did both now it has turned to red.rigg I follwed few of your tips on wamp forum but that too didn't work

Comment: @RiggsFolly Got you answer.
Changed user to root refreshed pages clearing cache.it worked