# installation of xampp in windows xp

Tags: php, apache, tomcat, apache2

I am installing xampp in my computer(Operating System -windows xp sp2 , dual core processor,1GB RAM) but in xampp Control Panel Apache not start it;s show Apache started [port 80]
Busy.
I think the file is corrupted or viruses so i formatted my computer and install from xampp cd
but this show same msg
Apache started [port 80]
Busy.

can U Help me

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is another application listening on port 80. You may need to find out which application  is using the port 80, then stop/kill that application/service before you could start the xampp server to listen on port 80.

[Look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960750/how-to-find-which-program-is-using-port-80-in-windows) to find out which application is currently using the port.

Answer (score 0):

if you used any message soft, you can try close them.
i know skype use port 80