# Apache Server Stops Using port 80

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I am using WAMP 2.4 (`Apache 2.4.4`). I am using this for hosting a sugarcrm. My Apache is running at port 80.

Now suddenly my apache server stops using port 80 and when I click on test port 80 its gives the message as

> 'Your port 80 is actually used by:'

then after 5 to 10 it says apache 2.4, but sometime it does not shows this also. Then I again restart the server and it works fine.

In an hour it happens arround  4-5 times.
When I see apache error log i gets following error messages

```
[Fri Nov 15 22:59:44.181794 2013] [mpm_winnt:warn] [pid 6840:tid 2912] (OS 64)The specified network name is no longer available.  : AH00341: winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.<br>
[Fri Nov 15 22:59:44.181794 2013] [mpm_winnt:warn] [pid 6840:tid 2912] (OS 64)The specified network name is no longer available.  : AH00341: winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.<br>
[Sat Nov 16 10:22:50.191164 2013] [mpm_winnt:warn] [pid 6840:tid 2912] (OS 64)The specified network name is no longer available.  : AH00341: winnt_accept: Asynchronous AcceptEx failed.
```

Please help me on this

Comment: what is your windows version ?

Comment: if you have Skype, turn it off also.

Comment: When I had this problem I started using port 8080 instead, never had any problems since...

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960750/how-to-find-which-program-is-using-port-80-in-windows as administrator in cmd.exe: `netstat -abn | findstr :80` will show you quickly if something is listening on port 80 or not (this will help isolate the problem). If yes, then `netstat -anb >%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ports.txt` and sift through the results.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure thsi is the solution but it can sometimes help and it will do no harm.

```
Open a command prompt as Administrator

Run
>netsh winsock reset

Reboot if necessary

Try apache again
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the following looking at the same set of errors and hangs. I found this URL in the apache lounge, this appears to be an issue only on the WINNT Apache systems.
https://www.apachelounge.com/viewtopic.php?p=28256

Excerpt from the post:

> When you have hangs, slow traffic and/or when having in your log
>   entries like Asynchronous AcceptEx failed. You can try the following
>   settings:
>
> AcceptFilter http none
>   AcceptFilter https none
>   EnableSendfile off
>   EnableMMAP off

This should be set in your HTTPD.CONF file.   Give it a try and see if it works.