# Point domain to go server with gorilla mux

Tags: go, gorilla

I have a small server and I want that server to listen to my custom domain sftablet.dev using gorilla/mux package.

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.Host("sftablet.dev")
    r.HandleFunc("/", HomeHandler)
    r.HandleFunc("/products", ProductsHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", r)
}

func HomeHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hey, this is homepage")
}

func ProductsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "Hey, this is products")
}
```

I also added this in the hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       sftablet.dev
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. It does work if I go to 127.0.0.1:8080, but not when I access http://sftablet.dev/. Also cleared the DNS cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http://sftablet.dev/` would by default query the port 80

Your server only listen to port 8080. `http://sftablet.dev:8080/` should work.

Comment: And if I try to access only with http://sftablet.dev? I tried http.ListenAndServe(":80", r) but it will not work

Comment: @zuzuleinen it will "now" work? or it will "not" work?

Comment: @zuzuleinen see also if your port 80 is not already taken: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1960759/6309