# apache cannot starting xammp apache service

Tags: php, apache, xampp, syntax-error

[image]

> Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. cannot starting Apache Xampp

Comment: Well, go ahead and check the logs and event viewer. We're not psychic.

Comment: Take a look here to see if `:80` is blocked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960759/1779433

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is nothing running on port 80. Check for Skype and other programs.
Or have a look at this SO question about changing ports: [How to change XAMPP apache server port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294812/how-to-change-xampp-apache-server-port)